# Model Dependency Diagram not available in RubyMine 5.4.2 using LinuxMint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine, linux-mint

I am using **RubyMine 5.4.2** on **Linux_Mint 16**. I cannot find **Model Dependency Model Diagram** option in it. But it is mentioned in its documentation.

**What I have tried**

- I tried commands Ctrl+ALt+U and CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+U (NOT WORKED)
- There is also **NO** option available in settings for Diagrams too.

I am working on an ROR application. I am new to this language and I need this feature. Anybody who may have encountered same problem in Ubuntu or in any other flavor of Linux, can give me a suggestion how to solve this problem?

Comment: Right click on code (in models). Diagrams -> Model Dependence (is i remember)

Comment: I already have told that there is no Diagrams option in menu. can u tell me? which file of **RM** executes dependency diagram

Comment: he said to right click so if you right click in the code or in the project view you'll see it. @itsnikolay i tried but the result was nothing opened up.

Answer (score 0):

Check plugins "Ruby UML Support Integration" and "UML Support" in Preferences > Plugins list. They should be enabled.